# How to accept multiple objects as an array in simple_form without associated objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form, ruby-on-rails-5

I need to do something similar to the gif example I'm posting. I'm using simple form and I have seen tons of examples on how to add associated objects, but the catch is that the array that I want to get in the controller "entries" is not an association, nor a property. I just need to receive something like this in the controller:

```
{:entries=>["first", "second", "third"]}
```

Any clue/blog post or anything? I'm completely lost!

[image: Sample]

Comment: accepts_nested_attibutes, otherwise use javascript to get the function of adding a new field. for instace you have a category with a field :name you can via button render a new field :name and submit it to the DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding a [ ] next to the input name. In your case:

```
<input type="text" name="entries[]">
```

Your controller will receive :entries param as an array with all the values of the inputs with name "entries[]" inside.